# Regex for extracing prices from text

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following price format : int_.*int*,_int_ _TL

Now the . is optional. It happens there when only the price is bigger than 1000.

Several example

```
54,12
540,44
5,11
3.331,55
```

How can I extract these kind of values from given string with using .NET regex? Thank you.

I am also using htmlagilitypack and if it is possible with it I would like to use it.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Well i am pretty bad with regex so could not try anything yet. The website structure is too bad so it is quite not possible extracting prices with site structure.

Comment: From your description and your example data, I don't understand which number you're targeting. Only the last one in the example? All of the 3.331? only the 331?

Comment: @m4tt1mus i am targeting all. I can iterate to extract all of those values. So think as a list which contains these values : 54,12 : 540,44 : 5,11 : 3.331,55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should cover you.. not an expert or anything but it works..

```
string test = @"<td width='150'><b><font color='#000000' face='Arial' size='5'> 1.777,00</font><font color='#000000' face='Arial' size='2'>&nbsp;TL<td width='150'><b><font color='#000000' face='Arial' size='5'> 395,00</font><font color='#000000' face='Arial' size='2'>&nbsp;TL";
var result = Regex.Matches(test,@"[1-9]*\.?[0-9]*,[0-9]*");
Console.Write(result);
```

Explained...

**[1-9]***** = Any number ( 1-9 ) and the ( * ) means multiple times. I set the first number to 1-9 because I am assuming you wont start a price with 0.

**\ .?** = the ( \ ) is an escape character for the ( . ) and the ( ? ) means it is optional.

**[0-9]***** = Again ( 0-9 ) multiple times

**,** = the desired separator you chose.

Check this out : http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: Hello tried this but found only one value while there are several. For example failed to find this  1.799,09 TL  . Yes i used Regex.Matches

Comment: hello. this is the example text and does not work. This is as far as i can simply from very badly codded shopping site :D http://pastebin.com/ZP8PGjmJ There are 4 values at this example that i need to extract via regex

Comment: Looks like you removed the TL so i removed it also from the RegEx... i apologize i used Match instead of Matches. try this and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more complete code snippet:

```
        var regex = @"^(?<Price>[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]+)?).*$";

        var regex2 = new Regex(regex);

        var matches = regex2.Matches("123.123,123 TL");

        Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups["Price"].Captures[0].ToString());
```

Comment: hello. It fails to find for example this value   <td width="150"><b><font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="5">
         1.777,00</font><font color="#000000" face="Arial" size="2">&nbsp;TL

Comment: use `@"^.* (?<Price>[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*,[0-9]+).*$"` instead. btw you should force htmlagilitypack to remove `font` tags. this makes processing much easier

Comment: yes i took innertext and tried. If found only 1 match and failed others. I am looking from matches object. This is the page that i am crawling : http://www.gold.com.tr/urunozelyeni.asp?ID=103244&ad=SAMSUNG-UE-40D5800-100HZ-102C-FULL-HD-LED-TV-%28DST%29-LCD-TV---LED-TV---Plazmalar

Comment: hello. this is the example text and does not work. This is as far as i can simply from very badly codded shopping site :D http://pastebin.com/ZP8PGjmJ There are 4 values at this example that i need to extract via regex